# Retrofit returns empty object, but json seems valid

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

This is the json I get from my endpoint. I got it using proxy, so this is exactly what retrofit gets:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "jacek@gmail.com",
    "name": "Jacek KwiecieŇĄ",
    "google_plus_id": "117434793312604634191",
    "facebook_id": null,
    "avatar_url": "https://some_url",
    "last_login_at": "2015-06-14T12:36:58.831Z",
    "created_at": "2015-06-14T12:36:58.829Z",
}
```

I create RetrofitService like this:

```
private static final RestAdapter REST_ADAPTER = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.SERVER_URL)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder().create()))
        .build();

public static final Api API = REST_ADAPTER.create(Api.class);
```

Finally here is my model class:

```
public class User {
    public long id;
    public boolean active;
    public String email;
    public String googlePlusId;
    public String facebookId;
    public String name;
    public String avatarUrl;
    public String coverPhotoUrl;
}
```

Why would retrofit return me an empty User object? Json is valid and no errors are thrown.

Comment: Are you getting json using postman or advance rest client???

Comment: Just get it as json string and then convert it into object.

Comment: I'm capturing json using charles proxy to be exact. You do realise it's not how retrofit works?

Comment: So what i am saying you is just capture json string and then convert it to object using `gson` lib, if you are getting empty object.

Comment: You clearly have no idea of retrofit library. It uses gson underneath to convert the json.

Comment: I have idea that's why saying that just capture json string and then convert it locally from your code to an object, that's what i have also done in one of my project.

Comment: Then you basically don't fully use retrofit advantages. It's not a way to go for me.

Comment: I was just suggesting you another way to do it.

Comment: Can you add your call to you api ? It could be usefull to have the log of retrofit to do so just add :  setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).
                setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                    @Override
                    public void log(String msg) {
                        Log.i(TAG, msg);
                    }
                }).

Comment: @Nicolas attached link to logs in the question

Comment: @Pankaj your solution works for me, but I'd like to know why JSONObject from org.json returns empty object while JsonObject from google.Gson return the proper json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the mock API which returns your JSON: http://www.mocky.io/v2/55867bf40258d3a80360db06

This demo works just fine:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.http.GET;

public class RetrofitDemo {

  static class User {

    public long id;
    public boolean active;
    public String email;
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("google_plus_id") public String googlePlusId;
    @SerializedName("facebook_id") public String facebookId;
    @SerializedName("avatar_url") public String avatarUrl;
    @SerializedName("cover_photo_url") public String coverPhotoUrl;
    @SerializedName("last_login_at") public String lastLoginAt;
    @SerializedName("created_at") public String createdAt;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "User{" +
          "id=" + id +
          ", active=" + active +
          ", email='" + email + '\'' +
          ", name='" + name + '\'' +
          ", googlePlusId='" + googlePlusId + '\'' +
          ", facebookId='" + facebookId + '\'' +
          ", avatarUrl='" + avatarUrl + '\'' +
          ", coverPhotoUrl='" + coverPhotoUrl + '\'' +
          ", lastLoginAt='" + lastLoginAt + '\'' +
          ", createdAt='" + createdAt + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }

  interface API {

    @GET("/55867bf40258d3a80360db06")
    User getUser();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    API api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://www.mocky.io/v2")
        .build()
        .create(API.class);

    System.out.println(api.getUser());
  }
}
```

### EDIT

From the logs I see your server responds with `Content-Type: application/json`. Try letting it respond with a specific encoding, say: `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Only differences I see is that you added @SerializedName annotations, and that I'm using RxJava observables. Added annotations but that doesn't change anything

Comment: Turns out it was all about that encoding. I probably managed to change it before you tried my endpoint. I guess I did not erase all my private data correctly from the logs, but it turned out well.